# How to deserialize mixed JSON and XML to classes

Tags: c#, json, xml, deserialization

I'm getting a response string from Azure DevOps REST API that contain mostly JSON, with some XML sprinkled into a few property values. I build a number of C# classes replicating the JSON structure of the response, in order to deserialize the response.

When

```
var response = client.Get(request);
if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK
    && response.Content != null)
{
    return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(response.Content);
}
```

reaches the XML in

```
public class Fields
{
    ...
    [JsonPropertyName("Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.Steps")]
    public Steps MicrosoftVSTSTCMSteps { get; set; }
}
```

I get a

`System.Text.Json.JsonException: 'The JSON value could not be converted to ADO.Response.Steps. Path: $.fields['Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.Steps'] | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 5149.'`

The Steps class is defined like

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "steps")]
public class Steps
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "step")]
    public Step[] Step { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "last")]
    public string Last { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

An exerpt of the incomming JSON/XML string looks like this:

```
{
  ...
  "Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.Steps":"<?xml version="1.0"?><steps last="5" id="0"><step id="2"  type="ActionStep"><parameterizedString isformatted="true"></parameterizedString><description /></step></steps><xml/>
  ...
}
```

How do I deserialize the JSON and the XML without detaching the Steps class from the hierarchy by e.g keeping the XML as a string in the deserialized JSON?

I'm looking to avoid post processing like this

```
XmlSerializer XmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Steps));
Steps steps = (Steps)XmlSerializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(resp.fields.MicrosoftVSTSTCMSteps));
```

Comment: And where is you json and xml strings? How do you think we can help you if we don't have any idea what are trying to deserilize?

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable?view=net-7.0

Comment: @jdweng If you've got an example of how that would work for me, I'd love to accept it as an answer.

Comment: You're looking for a deserializer that can deserialize both json and xml?  If you want to keep the fields typed (instead of strings), you probably will have to write your own 2-step deserializer that does the json, then the xml.  Alternatively, keep the xml string properties and add companion properties that deserialize the xml strings under the hood and handle the xml types.

Comment: Is the XML really just sitting there unescaped within the JSON? Not even MS would produce such a mess ... I suppose it's more looking like this `{"foo": "<?xml version=\"1.0\"><steps last=\"5\" id=\"0\">...<\steps></xml>" }` Ie the XML is embedded as an escaped string, right?

Comment: Typically you solve this type of problem by using [custom converters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-7-0) Work through the docs and try it. If you don't get it to work, post your code here ...

Comment: @derpirscher The raw string is escaped. What's pasted into this question, is the output after being parsed as a string by the json deserializer.

Comment: @PebermynteLars the json string that you posted is not valid , you will not be even able to deserialize the json. Pls post a valid example that can be tested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A custom converter became my best solution, using `System.Text.Json`, `System.Text.Json.Serialization` and `System.XML.Serialization`.
I can now use the regular property attributes and keep the deserialization in one neat flow.

```
        // Request an ADO resource and deserialize the JSON response with embedded XML into C# classes.
        private static T? Get<T>(string resource, RestClient client)
        {
            var request = new RestRequest()
            {
                Resource = resource
            };

            var response = client.Get(request);
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK
                && response.Content != null)
            {
                // Create a custom deserializer for mixed json and xml content
                var options = new JsonSerializerOptions()
                {
                    Converters = { new MixedJsonXmlConverter() }
                };

                // Deserialize mixed json and xml content from response
                return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(response.Content, options);
            }

            return default;
        }
```

The custom converter that picks up on `Steps` properties that contain XML targeted for deserialization, looks like this:

```
    internal class MixedJsonXmlConverter : JsonConverter<Steps>
    {
        // Deserialize Microsoft.VSTSTCMSteps of Steps data type stored in the JSON response, as XML.
        // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0#registration-sample---converters-collection
        // Support property attributes equal to stock deserialization of JSON and XML.
        public override Steps? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            // Read XML string and parse it to object of type Steps
            var xml = reader.GetString();
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Steps));

            using var stringReader = new StringReader(xml);
            return (Steps)serializer.Deserialize(stringReader);

        }

        public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Steps value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

If I bump into other JSON properties that needs to be deserialized as XML, I can use the same pattern.

So now I can address the response as one cohesive data structure like:

```
var workItem = Get<CaseWorkItem>(resource, client);

Console.WriteLine($"Property in JSON response: {workItem.fields.SystemAreaPath}");
Console.WriteLine($"Property in XML response: {workItem.fields.MicrosoftVSTSTCMSteps.Id}")
```

Answer (score 1):

It is much easier to do using Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeXNode to convert xml to json

```
var jNode = System.Text.Json.Nodes.JsonObject.Parse(content);
var fields = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Fields>(jNode);

var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeXNode(XElement.Parse((string)jNode["Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.Steps"]));

fields.MicrosoftVSTSTCMSteps = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Root>(json).steps;
```

classes

```
public class Fields
{
    [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonIgnore]
    public Steps MicrosoftVSTSTCMSteps { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public Steps steps { get; set; }
}

public class ParameterizedString
{
    [JsonPropertyName("@isformatted")]
    public string Isformatted { get; set; }
}

public class Step
{
    [JsonPropertyName("@id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("@type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    
   [JsonPropertyName("parameterizedString")]
    public ParameterizedString ParameterizedString { get; set; }
}

public class Steps
{
    [JsonPropertyName("@last")]
    public string Last { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("@id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    
    [JsonPropertyName("step")]
    public Step Step { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See solution below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Xml.Schema;
using System.Text.Json;

namespace ConsoleApp10
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\myprogram.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
 

        }
    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "steps")]
    public class Steps : IXmlSerializable
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "step")]
        public Step[] Step { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "last")]
        public string Last { get; set; }

        public JsonElement json { get; set; }

        [XmlText]
        public string text
        {
            get { return JsonSerializer.Serialize(json); }
            set { json = (JsonElement) JsonSerializer.Deserialize(value, typeof(JsonElement)); }
        }

        public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
        {
        }

        public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
        {
        }

        public XmlSchema GetSchema()
        {
            return (null);
        }

    }
    public class Step
    {

    }

}
```

Comment: Good write-up. Looks like this is for JSON inside XML. I've got XML inside JSON.